# How to make the inner shape transparent using the Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to figure out how to make this inner object that is now white to be transparent using Illustrator? Tnx

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Assuming your white shape is intended to make the black transparent, you have a couple of options:

1) be sure that your white shape is a single object which has a fill. Goto the pathfinder panel and subtract it from the black shape. If the white object is a stroke and a white circle, outline the stroke at first and unite the circle and the outlined stroke before the subtraction or subtract them separately

2) A non-destructive way: the white object is used as opacity mask, but inverted. It still must be a single object.

An example:

[image]

The creation of the mask needs selecting both and clicking the small hamburger icon in the top right corner of the transparency panel.

To stay in the truth, you have still plenty of options left, but I see them impractical. You can for example

- subtract the white shape from a big square and use the remnants of the square as a clipping mask for the black shape
- draw a new shape that has just the wanted, a little complex outline

Answer (score 1):

[image: Work process]

The only way to is to subtract - for getting the desired result for your image posted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both are different shapes, select both and press alt+subtract in pathfinder.Now it will become compound shape so that u can edit both the objects for later use.